# cannot convert map(None, ...) with multiple arguments because map() now truncates to the shortest sequence

Tags: python

```
RefactoringTool: ### In file server\euclid.py ###
RefactoringTool: Line 147: cannot convert map(None, ...) with multiple arguments because map() now truncates to the shortest sequence
RefactoringTool: Line 147: cannot convert map(None, ...) with multiple arguments because map() now truncates to the shortest sequence
RefactoringTool: Line 367: cannot convert map(None, ...) with multiple arguments because map() now truncates to the shortest sequence
RefactoringTool: Line 367: cannot convert map(None, ...) with multiple arguments because map() now truncates to the shortest sequence
RefactoringTool: ### In file server\Predefs\Heroes\Sniper.py ###
RefactoringTool: Line 192: You should use a for loop here
```

When trying to convert python 3 to 3, I am getting above error.

Anyone can advice

Comment: scope_tokens = attr.get( ("Abilities", "Scope", "Tokens") ) LINE 147

Comment: for c, v in map(None, name, value):   LINE 147 AND 367

Comment: You can use `itertools.starmap` and `itertools.zip_longest` together.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For help with your code, you need to provide a [mre], that is, show us a small example of some code that will raise this warning, as well as how you're calling the converter (which seems to be `RefactoringTool`). Please [edit] to add details, cause comments are meant to be temporary. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: "3 to 3" should be "2 to 3", right?

Comment: Have you done any research? For example, this existing question: [Using map with multiple args](/q/20646996/4518341)

Comment: scope_tokens = attr.get( ("Abilities", "Scope", "Tokens") )   and another line: for c, v in map(None, name, value):     can someone rewrite this two line for python3